# Font Rendering Error in Python

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, render

I am currently working on rendering a font for my game in python 3.2.3 and pygame.  I am currently getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\FinalProject.py", line 249, in <module>
    drawLevel1(screen, guy)
  File "E:\FinalProject.py", line 107, in drawLevel1
    text = font.render("Level : %s" % (lvlNum), 1, (0,0,0))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'render'
```

with the following code:

```
pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.SysFont("Grobold", 20)
if lvlNum == level1 or lvlNum == level2 or lvlNum == level3:
    text = font.render("Level : %s" % (lvlNum), 1, (0,0,0))
```

I do not know why this error is occurring.  Any help with this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In stead of using `pygame.font.SysFont("Grobold", 20)` you probably want to do:

```
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Grobold", 20) #Assign it to a variable font
text = font.render("Hello", 1, (0,0,0)) #Call render from the font variable
```